# Use a custom function in dplyr summarise(across())

Tags: r, dplyr, custom-function

This works as intended:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(minutes = c(89,90,91),
             var1 = c(89, 90, 91),
             var2 = c(50, 100, 150))
df %>% 
  summarise(across(c(var1, var2), list(p90 = ~ .x / minutes * 90)))
```

However, when I try to turn it into a function. This does not work.

```
p90 <- function(df, ..., minutes = minutes){
  
  p90.fn <- list(p90 = ~ .x / minutes * 90)
  
  df %>% 
    summarise(across(vars(...), p90.fn))
  
}

df %>% p90(var1,var2)
```

All the answers on here point me to needing a {{}} somewhere but I'm at a lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `vars` to `c`

```
p90 <- function(df, ..., minutes = minutes){
  
   p90.fn <- list(p90 = ~ .x / minutes * 90)
  
   df %>% 
     summarise(across(c(...), p90.fn))
  
 }
```

-testing

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    p90(var1,var2)
 var1_p90 var2_p90
1       90  50.5618
2       90 100.0000
3       90 148.3516
```